# json.Marshal vs Encoder.Encode

Tags: json, go

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Student struct {
    Firstname, lastname string
    Email               string
    Age                 int
    HeightInMeters      float64
    IsMale              bool
}

func main() {
    john := Student{
        Firstname:      "John",
        lastname:       "Doe",
        Age:            21,
        HeightInMeters: 1.75,
        IsMale:         true,
    }

    johnJSON, _ := json.Marshal(john) // johnJSON is of type []byte
    fmt.Println(string(johnJSON))     // print it in characters

}
```

---

`johnJSON, _ := json.Marshal(john)` is encoding a struct type(`john`) to `[]byte`.

---

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Student struct {
    Firstname, lastname string
    Email               string
    Age                 int
    HeightInMeters      float64
    IsMale              bool
}

func main() {
    john := Student{
        Firstname:      "John",
        lastname:       "Doe",
        Age:            21,
        HeightInMeters: 1.75,
        IsMale:         true,
    }

    // johnJSON, _ := json.Marshal(john) // johnJSON is of type []byte
    // fmt.Println(string(johnJSON))     // print it in characters

    // create a buffer to hold JSON data
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    // create JSON encoder for `buf`
    bufEncoder := json.NewEncoder(buf)

    bufEncoder.Encode(john)
    // print contents of the `buf`
    fmt.Println(buf) // calls `buf.String()` method
}
```

---

`bufEncoder.Encode(john)` is marshaling struct type(`john`) to `io.Writer` type(`buf`)

---

When to use `json.Marshal()` vs `Encoder.Encode()`? Because both `buf` and `johnJSON` are `[]byte` type

```
type Buffer struct {
    buf      []byte // contents are the bytes buf[off : len(buf)]
    off      int    // read at &buf[off], write at &buf[len(buf)]
    lastRead readOp // last read operation, so that Unread* can work correctly.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are three differences.

- The application can set encoding options on the [encoder](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Encoder). Examples are [SetEscapeHTML](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Encoder.SetEscapeHTML) and [SetIndent](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Encoder.SetIndent).  There are no options with the Marshal function.
- The Marshal function encodes the JSON document to a single `[]byte` that must be in memory.  The [encoder](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Encoder) writes data through to the underlying [io.Writer](https://godoc.org/io#Writer), thus avoiding the need to have the entire encoded document in memory.
- To support [streams of JSON documents](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#example-Decoder-Decode-Stream), the encoder adds a whitespace byte after each JSON document. See https://play.golang.org/p/Apb5GJeEcQq for the difference. The extra whitespace is ignored by JSON parsers.

If the feature differences between the Marshal function and Encoder type do not dictate a choice between them, then use the one that's most convenient. The Marshal function and Encoder type share most of their implementation and have similar performance. The Marshal function is not a wrapper around the Encoder as claimed in a different answer.

Comment: "The encoder writes data through to the underlying io.Writer, thus avoiding the need to have the entire encoded document in memory." -- This is untrue. The entire output is buffered internally, before writing to the `io.Writer`, much to the [chagrin of myself, and a few others](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33714).

Answer (score 3):

`Marshal` (`Unmarshal`) is a wrapper around `Encoder` (`Decoder`). They are mainly convenience functions that provide a convenient interface to the lower level encoder/decoder implementations.

If you need to process JSON streams containing more than one JSON document, or if you need to process a JSON stream without unmarshaling the whole document to an in-memory structure, use decoder. If you have a `Reader`, you can use `Decoder` instead of `Unmarshal`.

Similarly, if you are generating JSON stream without an in-memory structure, or are writing multiple JSON documents into a stream, use `Encoder`. If you have a `Writer`, you can use an encoder without first unmarshaling to a byte array and then writing it.